# why am I not getting data which i append in the dictionary in output.csv

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

l1 = {"name": [], "order no": [], "price": []}
df = pd.DataFrame(l1)
while (True):
  exit = input("enter exit to exit: ")
  name = input("enter your name: ")
  order_no = int(input("enter your order no: "))
  price = int(input("enter your price: "))
  printing = input("type print to print data: ")
  if (exit == "exit" or printing == "print"):
    df.to_csv("output.csv")
    break
  else:
    l1["name"].append(name)
    l1["order no"].append(order_no)
    l1["price"].append(price)
    print(l1)
```

I am not getting data which I append in  dictionary (l1) in output.csv file

Comment: Put `df.to_csv("output.csv")` code outside "else"

Answer (score 1):

Move your "df" variable declaration before you save to_csv()

You declare df with init dict, but add data to dict dont change data in DataFrame

```
...
if (exit == "exit" or printing == "print"):
    df = pd.DataFrame(l1) #<<<<<<<<<<<
    df.to_csv("output.csv")
    break
...
```